# Upsert SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am looking for some advice how to optimize a couple of SQL stored procedures.  With the 1st query I am doing insert, and with the 2nd one I am doing update, if the data exists.

What I want to do is merge both stored procedures in one, where the query will check if the data exists than update, else insert a new row.

Here is what I have at this time:

update SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateStep1](@UserId nvarchar(50), @First_Name nvarchar(50), @Last_Name nvarchar(50),
                             @TitlePosition nvarchar(30))                                                   
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE Company_Information
SET First_Name = @First_Name,
    Last_Name = @Last_Name,
    Title_Position=@TitlePosition,  
    WHERE UserId = @UserId
    END
```

insert SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertStep1](@UserId nvarchar(50), @First_Name nvarchar(50), @Last_Name nvarchar(50),
                             @TitlePosition nvarchar(30))
                            
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Company_Information(UserId,
                                    First_Name,
                                    Last_Name,
                                    Title_Position)
                                    
                                    VALUES
                                    (@UserId,
                                    @First_Name,
                                    @Last_Name,
                                    @TitlePosition)
END
```

So, I would like to merge both SP in one, and the SP to check if there is already data for that UserId than update, else insert a new row.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[MERGE Statement?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MERGEStep1](@UserId nvarchar(50), @First_Name nvarchar(50), @Last_Name nvarchar(50), @TitlePosition nvarchar(30))                                                   
AS
BEGIN
MERGE Company_Information WITH(HOLDLOCK) AS T
USING(SELECT 1 S) S
ON T.UserId = @UserId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
  First_Name = @First_Name,
  Last_Name = @Last_Name,
  Title_Position=@TitlePosition  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (UserId, First_Name, Last_Name, Title_Position)
  VALUES(@UserId, @First_Name,@Last_Name,@TitlePosition);
END
```

Comment: +1 [Might need `HOLDLOCK` though](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx)

Comment: Can you update this query with the holdlock so that copy-pasters won't get the defective code?

Comment: Just a note for those less familiar with HOLDLOCK -> this hint is necessary to prevent your statement from being vulnerable to race conditions. See http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a variable to test it (ex: @id)
2. Select @id = UserId from Company_Information where UserId = @UserId
3. If @id = @userId update, otherwise insert

---

As @gbn specified, be aware of [concurrence issues](http://How%20SQL%20Server%20handles%20concurrent%20requests?).

Comment: This won't be concurrency safe. Two closely concurrent calls can both deduce that the row doesn't yet exist