# Stored procedure that takes list of string as input and insert missing rows then return them

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table `Names`

```
  Id         Name     
+----+---------------+
  1          John      
  2          Kate    
  3          Mark
```

I want to create a stored procedure that does the following:

**1) take a list of names as string as an input parameter**

I have done some researches about this but couldn't find the best way to do it. I will call the stored procedure from the entity framework in a C# application. I was thinking of passing the names in one string separated with a comma and the split them in the procedure. But can't figure out how this is done.

**2) for each name in the list, if the name does not exist in the `Name` column, insert a new row for it.**

How can I do a switch case if it exists and insert it if not

**3) Select * rows that are in the input list.**

After adding all the missing Names, I want to select all the names that were in the input list with their id

Can this be done in one stored procedure, or do I have to divide them into multiple.

I am looking for hints on how to do each step, and if they can be combined.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep your DB side lean and leave logic on the app side, especially if you have grumpy DBA's.

Use a MERGE/Upsert instead.

Check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701509/upsert-sql-query).

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a comma delimited list into a stored procedure as a parameter, you are going to need to understand how to use `charindex`, `left`, `substring` and `right`

As you split out each name - you would add them into a temporary table or a table valued variable.

Your decision about whether to `insert` the new names into the `Names` table would be made using an `exists()` subquery on an `insert` statement.

You could then, finally, fashion a select statement to `join` your temp table/table valued variable back to your `Names` table to pull out all of the keys (including the new ones) and pass them back to your front end.